# passing data in model trough controller in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I've heard about codeigniter couple of times so i was curious and thought why not. I took some tutorials and was very delighted to see how the framework worked. 
Now i've the following problem i want to passing the data i've made in my model trough my controller and showing this in my view but i always run to the folowing error: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\codeigniterTest\application\models\leden_model.php on line 9. The funny thing about this error is, when i google on this issue a lot of forum topics is about this issue but nowhere i get the right answer. my code looks like this.

codegniter version 2.03

```
class Leden extends CI_Controller {

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

function index()
{
    $this->load->model('leden_model');
    $ledenModel = new Leden_model();
    $data = $ledenModel->allLeden();
    $this->load->view('leden_overzicht',$data);
}
}


<?php
class Leden_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function allLeden(){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM leden");
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
           echo $row['Naam'];
           echo $row['Achternaam'];
           echo $row['Email'];
        }

        return $query;
    }

}
```

?>

When i'm doing the query in my controller then i'm getting the results i want, why not in my model?

my question is what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Just follow this url [Codeigniter's model class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html) Documentation of CI is very good, it will teach you everything in a very simple and elegent way.

Comment: thank you very much every source is more then welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Leden_model.php**

> ?php
>
> class Leden_model extends CI_Model {
>
> ```
> function __construct(){
>     parent::__construct();
> }
>
> function allLeden()
> {
>     $data = array();
>     $this->db->select();
>     $query = $this->db->get('leden');
>
>     if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
>     {
>         foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
>         {
>             $data[] = $row;
>         }
>     }
>     $query->free_result();
>     return $data;
> }
> ```

**Leden_controller.php**

> ?php
>
> class Leden extends CI_Controller {
>
> ```
> function __construct()
> {
>     parent::__construct();
>
>     $this->load->model('leden_model');
> }
> ```
>
> function index() {
>
> ```
> $data['leden_data'] = $this->ledenModel->allLeden();
> $this->load->view('leden_overzicht',$data); }
> ```
>
> }

**leden_overzicht.php**

> ?php
>
> if (count($leden_data)) 
>   {
>
> foreach ($leden_data as $key => $list) 
>   {
>
> echo $list['Naam'] . " " . $list['Achternaam'] . " " . $list['Email'] . "
> ";
>
> } }
>       else {
>       echo "No data."; }

Comment: Thank you very mu h cruiser i'll try this and see what happens. thank you very much

Comment: found some little errors, and this editor eaten some breaks in view, so you got 100% tested and fully working example here:

controller: http://pastie.org/2478770
model: http://pastie.org/2478773
view: http://pastie.org/2478775

Comment: still get the error Call to a member function select() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\codeigniterTest\application\models\leden_model.php on line 11 always getting that kind of error i just don't get it anymore... and when i'm commenting the select i get the error: 

Call to a member function get() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\codeigniterTest\application\models\leden_model.php on line 12 ans soo.. further

Comment: please take codes from pastie, which i'm attached above your answer, it's tested and working. if you still get that errors, than something is wrong with your installation of CI. tested on CI 2.0.2, PHP5.

Comment: i copy and paste your code you just send and still get the errors, i will try to install version 2.0.2 maybe that will work?

Comment: OK, i found where is the problem now. You didn't (auto)load database library.

edit application/config/autoload.php and set: 
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');

Comment: Ciuser, i autoloaded the library i'm pretty sure of that. But no i installed version 2.02 and that worked well so i think there is something wrong with version 2.o3. I want to thank you for your help.

Comment: P.S. i reproduced your errors (and you can also try that), just remove autoload of database library, and you will get exact the same errors as you get before: Call to a member function select()... or get() - if you comment the line which cause the first error.

Comment: Well in that case i give it a try tomorrow for now i going to get some sleep. here in holland it is 4:39 am. thanks once again

Comment: we are in the same timezone, i know what's the time ;) sleep well, i'm glad that my solution worked for you. good night.

Answer (score 0):

did you load database? example:

> $this->load->database();

Comment: yes i add that in my constructor of my model and now it gives the following error: 

Fatal error: Call to a member function database() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\codeigniterTest\application\models\leden_model.php on line 6

Comment: you must supply valid credentials and name of database in application/config/database.php

then try to autoload "database" library in application/config/autoload.php

Comment: I did that because when i'm running the same query in my controller i get the results. I also autoload database in my library in autoload.php

Comment: i think the problem is in your model, in the part where you "echoing". that works fine in controller, but when you try to echoing from model, you got problem.

Comment: I know the problem is in my model otherwise it would worked but my question is whats the problem.

Comment: you are doing it wrong, because you are trying to print data in model, and return it back to controller, and pass it to view.

i will attach you a working solution for a few minutes.

Comment: i'm waiting for your reply and very curious how you will handle this because i looking for a solution for 3 days now.